# how to change the hard-code path of sharelibrary in core dump file for debug

Tags: gdb

some sharelibrary path in core dump was hard-coded, if set solib-absolute-prefix, it seems gdb will search it from the value of solib-absolute-prefix + the hard-coded path of sharelibrary, how to change them to debug?

I have try solib-absolute-prefix and solib-search-path, but they will not work well

Answer (score 0):

The `solib-search-path` is *exactly* what you want.

> will not work well

You'll have to expand on what didn't work. Here is an example showing that `solib-search-path` *does* work:

```
mkdir /tmp/foo /tmp/bar
cd /tmp/foo

echo 'void foo() { abort(); }' | gcc -xc - -fPIC -shared -o foo.so -w
echo 'int main() {  foo(); return 0; }' | gcc -xc - -l:./foo.so
./a.out
Aborted (core dumped)
```

First, we look at the core with all the binaries in their original location:

```
gdb -q ./a.out core

Reading symbols from ./a.out...done.
[New LWP 142587]
Core was generated by `./a.out'.
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
#0  0x00007f9c6f1f9c37 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
56  ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f9c6f1f9c37 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
#1  0x00007f9c6f1fd028 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
#2  0x00007f9c6f5886ce in foo ()
#3  0x000000000040069b in main ()
```

This looks good. Now we move `foo.so` to `/tmp/bar`:

```
mv foo.so /tmp/bar
```

Analysing the same core no longer works (at least not well):

```
gdb -q ./a.out core
Reading symbols from ./a.out...done.
[New LWP 142587]

warning: Could not load shared library symbols for ./foo.so.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
Core was generated by `./a.out'.
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
#0  0x00007f9c6f1f9c37 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
56  ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f9c6f1f9c37 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
#1  0x00007f9c6f1fd028 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
#2  0x00007f9c6f5886ce in ?? ()
#3  0x00007ffdaa9b74e0 in ?? ()
#4  0x000000000040069b in main ()
Backtrace stopped: frame did not save the PC
```

Finally we set `solib-search-path`, and it works again:

```
(gdb) set solib-search-path /tmp/bar
Reading symbols from /tmp/bar/foo.so...done.
WARNING: no debugging symbols found in /tmp/bar/foo.so.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f9c6f1f9c37 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
#1  0x00007f9c6f1fd028 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
#2  0x00007f9c6f5886ce in foo ()
#3  0x000000000040069b in main ()
```